# MVC/LINQ Search Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Ok to start I am a complete novice with MVC and LINQ and Razor.  These are the skills I am currently working with trying to learn them as I go.

I have a view that when you first visit the page it lists the entire table by default.  On this page I have two drop down boxes that are filled with values I would like to filter the results by.

How do I make it so when a user selects a value that is not the default value it reloads the page and then filters the data by whichever drop down they selected?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var docs = db.GetData();


    return View(docs);
}
```

Here is my dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FunctionList", "Select a Function")
```

Whenever they select a value that is not the "Select a Function" I want it to reload the page and then show the filtered data.

Comment: By Ajax or by posting back a form.  See http://forums.asp.net/t/1473546.aspx/1 or google for a tutorial on mvc grid filtering.

Comment: @SamLeach I would LOVE to do it by AJAX, but I've never done AJAX through .net or C# only with Jquery.  It frightens me.  I will look at the link you posted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, I'm afraid you will have to add JQuery to the list of skills needed for your project :)

You need, using JQuery, to create a handler for the change event on your DropDownList. In that event handler, post datas to another Action Method, like this one:

```
public ActionResult Filter(int id)
{
    var docs = db.GetData().Where(d => d.Id == id);

    return View("Index", docs);
}
```

You can do that, by simply calling the Url /{YourController}/Filter/{TheValueForId}.

When you're starting in MVC and LINQ, this is definitely not the best test case you could pick (if you picked it).

If you have the choice, try simpler things as a start.

Comment: Jquery is something I am fluent in thankfully! :)  i assume I can change `int id` to `string function`?  Although I have never used Jquery to post to action events, I assume the syntax isn't that different.

Comment: Yes, the "int id" was just for the exemple. You can basically post any kind of data you want with JQuery, and add in your method the equivalent .NET type as parameter. For example, if you post a json DateTime to an MVC Action Method, simply add a DateTime parameter, with the same name, and .NET will automatically parse the datetime received into a .NET DateTime object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript and subscribe to the `change` event of the dropdown and then reload the current page by passing the selected value to the server. Alternatively you could use an AJAX call to the server to refresh only the table portion of the view. In this case you will need to put the table in a partial view that will get included by the main view and you will use AJAX to call a controller action and pass the currently selected value of the dropdown which will be used to filter the results and return a partial.

For example, with jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#FunctionList').change(function() {
            var selectedFunction = $(this).val();
            if (selectedFunction != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selectedFunction: selectedFunction }
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#resultsContainer').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You could also include the selected value of the second dropdown if needed:

```
data: { 
    selectedFunction: $(this).val(),
    someOtherValue: $('#SomeOtherDropDown').val()
}
```

and your controller action will use those values to filter the results and pass it to a partial view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string selectedFunction, string someOtherValue) 
{
    IEnumerable<SomeResultModel> results = ...
    return PartialView(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll use something like this. This is a Telerik Grid example.

```
$('#btnFilter).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var new_data = getData();
    grid.dataSource.data(new_data);
});

function getData() {
    var _resData;
    var name= $('#txtName').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/MyContoller/Index/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: name},
        success: function (data) {
            _resData = data; 
        },
        data: {},
        async: false
    });
    return _resData;
}
```

In this example the Controller is "My Controller" and action is "Index"